# http.get not working in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I've got the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<div ng-app="">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    <p ng-bind="name">{{$http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=b4e5192d902f5add71f4a431c004d734').success(successCallback);}}</p>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=b4e5192d902f5add71f4a431c004d734').success(successCallback: 'JSON_CALLBACK');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it is not returning anything, how do I make it so I can at least just display everything in that API? I would like to assign it to an variable and be able to explode it for manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first define an app and a controller, and call $http inside it. In your HTML you can display the data that gets passed into the callback. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    <p>{{ data }}</p>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('App', []).
controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=b4e5192d902f5add71f4a431c004d734').success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data; 
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your `$http.get` call.  The options inside of `.success` need to be surrounded with curly braces, as they're an object.

Also, you're trying to use `$http` before it's been defined.

Answer (score 0):

The http call should be made in a controller. Angular services are not accessible directly in the html or immediately in a script block. I'm sure if you checked the console window you would see at least a couple of errors in what you have put here.

Basically when the data is returned the controller can assign the returned data onto a variable on the scope.

I'm going to guess your new to angular in which case there are many great resources online to guide you though making these first basic steps. Checkout https://egghead.io/articles/new-to-angularjs-start-learning-here.